# Concurrency semaphore sequential execution

Tags: go, operating-system, semaphore, synchronous, sequential

How can I execute a Go program in concurrency using semaphore sequentially?

I have a small program which just prints reading from an array which contain numbers

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "sync"

type empty struct{}

 type semaphore chan empty

 // acquire n resources
 func (sem semaphore) P(n int) {
 e := empty{}
 for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    sem <- e
 }
 }
 // release n resources
 func (sem semaphore) V(n int) {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        <-sem
     }
 }


func main() {
var wg sync.WaitGroup
sm := make(semaphore, 2)
var arr []int = []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

for _,val := range arr{
wg.Add(1)
go func(val int){
    sm.P(1)
    defer sm.V(1)
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Print(" val:",val)
      }(val)
}
wg.Wait()
}
```

Output:

9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

But I want the output to be like this (as per the array declaration)

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A semaphore or mutex controls synchronization, not order of operations. The order of concurrent operations, regardless of whether or not they're synchronized, is not controllable or predictable. If you need a controlled order of operations, you should not execute those operations concurrently.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Adrian . But what is the solution to the problem. So my problem statement is this .  I want to hit a third party API for some range of dates sequentially , and i should not do 10 API call at a time ,so i used a concurrency of 8 , so i wont do more than 10 calls . Now in this way ,i am able to call the API but not sequentially. sequential call is very important in my case . thanks

Comment: @SharathB.J I don't understand what you mean. If you want to call the API sequentially then you can't call it in parallel. The natural model has one thread hitting it sequentially. You're trying to exploit parallelism at the other end (e.g. you hit it with 10 sequential requests and then await the results) you either open 10 requests then wait on 10 results. You can parallelise that by creating 1 producer and a thread pool of consumers for the responses.

Comment: @sharath the solution is don't make your requests concurrently.